# Square root of positive operators.

Tags: functional-analysis

I want to prove this:

Let H a Hilbert space and $S,T\in B(H)$  such that $ST=TS$ and $$0\leq S\leq T.$$ Show that  $$0\leq \sqrt S\leq \sqrt T.$$

I have proved that, for $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $0\leq S^n \leq T^n.$ I tried a similar way for proving with the squares but nothing came up. Also I have tried to use that $\sqrt{TS}=\sqrt T \sqrt S=\sqrt S \sqrt T$ but I can't see how.

Comment: Are $S$ and $T$ self-adjoint?

Comment: The self-adjointness of $S$  is implicit in "$S\ge 0$", etc.

Comment: Yes, they are, as @JohnDawkins pointed.

Comment: Murphy, C*-Algebras and Operator Theory, Theorem 2.2.6

Comment: Thanks @Freeze_S that's what I was looking for =)

Comment: @JoséLuis: You're welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

$\sqrt{\sqrt{S}+\sqrt{T}}$ is a positive operator that commutes with everything that commutes with $\sqrt{S}+\sqrt{T}$, which includes $\sqrt{S}$ and $\sqrt{T}$. Therefore,
$$
        \sqrt{\sqrt{S}+\sqrt{T}}(\sqrt{T}-\sqrt{S})\sqrt{\sqrt{S}+\sqrt{T}} \\
  = (\sqrt{T}-\sqrt{S})(\sqrt{T}+\sqrt{S})=T-S \ge 0.
$$
Thus $\sqrt{T}-\sqrt{S}$ is positive on $\mathcal{M}=\overline{\mathcal{R}(\sqrt{S}+\sqrt{T})}$. And $\sqrt{T}-\sqrt{S}=0$ on the orthogonal complement of $\mathcal{M}$, which is
$$
          \mathcal{M}^{\perp}=\mathcal{N}(\sqrt{S}+\sqrt{T})=\mathcal{N}(\sqrt{S})\cap\mathcal{N}(\sqrt{T}).
$$
Both $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{M}^{\perp}$ are invariant under $\sqrt{T}-\sqrt{S}$. So $\sqrt{T}-\sqrt{S} \ge 0$.